# Gulp generate manifest files for existing files

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to automatically generate manifest files with gulp, but can't find how to get filename, modify it and send it forward through pipe.

```
var fs = require('fs');    
var content = 'test';
gulp.src('./wwwroot/**/*.file')
    .pipe(fs.writeFileSync(??? , content))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/')); // should be same as original file
```

Where `???` on 4th line is, I'd like to have `filename.file.manifest`.
Code above is more of an idea, since gulp.dest and fs both write file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with pipes, but nonetheless a nice solution using node [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

```
var content = 'test'

glob("./wwwroot/**/*.file", null, function(er, files) {
    if(er)
        return;

    files.forEach(function(element) {
        var manifestFile = element + '.manifest';
        fs.writeFileSync(manifestFile, content);
        console.log("Generated: " + element);
    });
})
```